# Error when pushing to Heroku caused by hoe 3.7.3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, heroku-postgres

Have ran into a problem pushing to heroku with the hoe gem, I have tried to remove it from gemfile.lock, but when I bundle it reinstalls. Have tried older versions of hoe but no luck with those either.

Using Ruby 1.9.2 / Rails 3.2.13

Here is a gists of the results when pushing to heroku:  https://gist.github.com/JRizzle88/8055546

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You dont **ever** edit the Gemfile.lock. You edit the Gemfile. Gemfile.lock is generated when you run `bundle install`

Comment: There is no evidence in the error log that he changed the Gemfile.lock

Comment: What I meant by removing it from the gemfile.lock is deleting gemfile.lock and running bundle install again to regenerate a new gemfile.lock

Comment: Doesn't matter, you need to remove the gem from the Gemfile or else it will automatically show up in Gemfile.lock. If the gem is not in the Gemfile, maybe it is a dependency of a gem that is not supported on heroku